# Angular 2 rc 1: Routing with LocationStrategy causing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined"

Tags: typescript, angular, routes, annotations, router

I've been trying to figure out Angular 2's "LocationStrategy" to prevent browser refresh from causing a 404 error. I am trying to provide HashLocationStrategy to my App Component but am getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined" error:

```
VM69529:77 TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined
at ReflectionCapabilities.annotations (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:1359), <anonymous>:142:40)
at Reflector.annotations (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:1365), <anonymous>:96:48)
at DirectiveResolver.resolve (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:727), <anonymous>:23:44)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:1197), <anonymous>:55:51)
at RuntimeCompiler.resolveComponent (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:1203), <anonymous>:34:47)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:793), <anonymous>:99:37)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:793), <anonymous>:292:26)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.bundle.js:2764), <anonymous>:323:29)
at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:1377), <anonymous>:45:41)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.bundle.js:2764), <anonymous>:322:35)
at Zone.run (eval at <anonymous> (polyfills.bundle.js:2764), <anonymous>:216:44)
at NgZoneImpl.runInner (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:1377), <anonymous>:76:71)
at NgZone.run (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:883), <anonymous>:223:66)
at ApplicationRef_.run (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:793), <anonymous>:290:14)
at Object.coreLoadAndBootstrap (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:793), <anonymous>:96:19)
at Object.bootstrap (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:2038), <anonymous>:91:19)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main.bundle.js:770), <anonymous>:26:28)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:770)
at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js:51)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main.bundle.js:806), <anonymous>:6:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:806)
at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js:51)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main.bundle.js:932), <anonymous>:17:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:932)
at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js:51)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js:6)
at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js:51)
at webpackJsonpCallback (polyfills.bundle.js:22)
at main.bundle.js:1
```

Here is what I have in my "app.component.ts" :

```
import { RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { provide, bind } from '@angular/core';
import {  
  PlatformLocation,  
  Location,  
  LocationStrategy,  
  HashLocationStrategy,  
  PathLocationStrategy,  
  APP_BASE_HREF}  
from '@angular/common'; 

import { BrowserPlatformLocation } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';


bootstrap(App, 
  [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
    bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue('/'), 
    provide( LocationStrategy, { useClass:HashLocationStrategy }) 
  ]);
```

Has anyone run into this as well?

Comment: Would you be able to put up a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TBjO78YYc4TtrTHzTVpb?p=info) of your setup?

Comment: which version of angular are you using ?

Comment: "It occurs when a directive is null or undefined" as stated here https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/1917

Comment: still figuring this out:

I simplified my setup into this Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/KuDNvUX1QkmeEKxmjOaY?p=preview